# How can I store images in cache memory using objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, crash

I am having problem when multiple images are being displayed in scrollview (photo Gallery). **I have fetched images from document directory.** when I display more then 100 images **application is getting crashed**. so I want to store images in cache memory.

I want to display first 15 images and then other from cache memory. when I scroll the `scrollview` first 15 from cache will be displayed and then next will be displayed.

The requirement is to display images in `scrollview` not in `collectionView` or other component.

`files` is `array` of image paths fetched from documents directory.

I have fetched all images path and stored in `files array`.

```
int x=2,y=5;
for (int i = 0; i < files.count ; i++)
 {
   if(x<=308)
    {
       NSString *setPath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",filePath,[files objectAtIndex:i]];
       UIImage* imagePath = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:setPath];
       imgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 77, 75)];
       imgView.image=imagePath; 
       x+=80;
    }
    else
    {
        x=2;
        y+=77;

        NSString *setPath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",filePath,[files objectAtIndex:i]];
        UIImage* imagePath = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:setPath];
        imgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 77, 75)];
        imgView.image=imagePath;
        x+=80;
    }
        [gallaryScrollView addSubview:imgView];
        [self.view addSubview:gallaryScrollView];
         gallaryScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, y+120);
 }
```

Comment: you use SDWebImage library https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage.

Comment: use ALAsset to fetch images

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya - I agree that if you need to load images from web service asynchronously and enjoy caching as you do that, SDWebImage is a great tool. But I think the problem here is far more fundamental, less of a caching issue and more of a "lazy loading and releasing as they scroll out of view" problem. And SDWebImage does nothing to address this problem.

Comment: Ravi - Why don't you want to use collection view (which is simply a scroll view which automatically takes care of the memory issues which are plaguing your current design)? Sure, you can write `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods that add and remove image views as they scroll in and out of view, but why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Rob - I agree with your suggestion but same issue in  collection view  crash application when more then 100 images.

Comment: OK, then solve that problem. One of two problems are possible: First, you might be holding on to the `UIImage` objects (e.g. holding them in some collection). You don't want to do that. When a cell is reused, you want to make sure you discard the `UIImage` object previously associated with that cell. Do not hold the image in memory. Second, you might be using images that are high resolution: E.g. if you have 4,000 x 4,000 pixel images that you load into a 100x100 image views, it's still going to take up 64mb per image unless you manually resize the image to a size appropriate for the cell.

Comment: The bottom line is that whether using collection view or scroll view with image views, you need to make sure that (a) you're releasing the `UIImage` objects for imageviews that have scrolled off screen; and (b) that the image  objects are appropriately sized for the image view that they're being used within, because a high resolution image in a small image view still requires a  lot of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Caching isn't going to solve your memory problem. (If anything, using additional memory cache only places more memory strain on the app.) You use cache for performance reasons, not for reducing memory usage.

The issue is that you're attempting to load image views into scroll view up front. I'd suggest doing lazy loading of the image views and their associated images. And rather than doing it in batches of 15 (or whatever), I'd suggest doing it dynamically in your [`UIScrollViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html) methods:

- setting `delegate` for your scroll view;
- implement `scrollViewDidScroll` which will:

  - remove any image views from the scroll view that are not visible (or near, at the very least)
  - add any image views that have scrolled into view and set its `image` property

If you want to marry this with `NSCache` for caching for performance reasons, you can do that if you want, but I'd suggest focusing on the main manual scroll view delegate implementation first.

Comment: Thanks Rob for your suggestion. i am new in IPhone  I don't know how can i implement. Please help me if any demo.

Comment: I don't know how can i remove or add imageView when scrolling.

Comment: First you have to get the `CGRect` for what portion of the the scroll view is visible (e.g. use `contentOffset` to get the `x` and `y` and use the `frame` to get the `width` and `height`). Then you can iterate though the image views and remove any for which `CGRectIntersectsRect` with the visible rect and the image view `frame` don't match up. But I personally think it's crazy to go through all of that work. Use `UICollectionView` (which does this for you) and figure out why you're running into memory problems.